# How to prevent find -execdir from following symlinks?

Tags: find, symlink, exec

Say I have a symlink:

`linktob -> b`

If I run something like `find . -type l -execdir chmod 777 {} \;`, the `chmod` command affects the file the symlink is pointing to, i.e. ‘b’.

The man page suggests that symlinks aren’t followed by default, but that doesn’t seem to be the case here.

How can I get `-execdir`, `-exec` etc. to work on the symlink itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can see from this example that the `find` command **does** actually operate on the symlink:

```
$ ls -l *
subdir1:
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 0 Jun 13 09:20 realfile

subdir2:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 19 Jun 13 09:20 symlinkfile -> ../subdir1/realfile
$ find . -type l -exec ls "{}" \;
./subdir2/symlinkfile
```

But the underlying command (e.g. `chmod`) might not. In this example, we can see that chmod is actually changing the permissions of the **target** file:

```
$ find . -type l -exec chmod -v 777 "{}" \;
mode of `./subdir2/symlinkfile' retained as 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
$ find . -type l -exec chmod -v 444 "{}" \;
mode of `./subdir2/symlinkfile' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0444 (r--r--r--)

$ ls -l *
subdir1:
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 nate nate 0 Jun 13 09:20 realfile

subdir2:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 19 Jun 13 09:20 symlinkfile -> ../subdir1/realfile
```

from the chmod man page:

> chmod  never  changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions

What are you trying to do to the symlink, exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t realise that. The same is also true of chgrp and chown. Using -h (where supported) on these commands affects the symlink itself, but seems pointless other than to cause an error message in `ls` if you take off read privilege.

I’m in the process of tidying up permissions after we moved servers and the data was transferred over with silly permissions/user/group. I’ll need to make sure the `find` command only finds actual files and dirs otherwise I could end up changing settings in places like /usr or even /…